# Loop Unrolling in C

Tags: c, loops, optimization

I'm supposed to be optimizing a loop in C. The loop is as follows:

```
#define N_TIMES     600000
#define ARRAY_SIZE   10000

for (i = 0; i < N_TIMES; i++) {

            for (ptr = array; ptr < &array[ARRAY_SIZE]; ptr+=2) {

                    sum += *ptr;
                    sum1 += *ptr + 1;
            }

    }

sum += sum1;
```

We've been introduced to 3 types of optimization: loop unrolling, loop splitting, and using pointers in loops. I've successfully implemented pointers and splitting (the loop now runs about 50% faster than before) but every time I try to unroll the loop I get no boost in speed. Here's what I've been trying:

```
for (i = 0; i < N_TIMES; i++) {

            for (ptr = array; ptr < &array[ARRAY_SIZE]; ptr+=4) {

                    sum += *ptr;
                    sum += *ptr + 1;
                    sum1 += *ptr + 2;
                    sum1 += *ptr + 3;
            }

    }
```

This appears to do nothing. Am I just totally misunderstanding what loop unrolling is, or should I just continue incrementing ptr by 2 in the loop declaration until it works? Any and all help is appreciated!

Also, I understand that compilers do most of the optimization in today's world, but this is an assignment for a class and I must do it this way.

Comment: How are you compiling your code?  If you're including any of the `-O` flags, there's a good chance the loop is already unrolled if `N_TIMES` is known at compile time.

Comment: FYI, your two loops aren't equivalent. In the unrolled version, `sum` should get `*ptr` and `*ptr+2`, and `sum1` should get `*ptr+1` and `*ptr+3`.

Comment: Does anyone else spot the obvious problem? :)

Comment: Note that you have an operator precedence problem: `sum += *ptr + 1;` should be `sum += *(ptr + 1);`, and similarly for the other offsets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One, you are not correctly unrolling the loop. It should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < N_TIMES; i++) {
    for (ptr = array; ptr < &array[ARRAY_SIZE]; ptr+=4) {
        sum += *ptr;
        sum1 += *ptr + 1;
        sum += *(ptr+2);
        sum1 += *(ptr+2) + 1;
    }
}
```

Obviously it might be that the original loop isn't what you really wanted. But because you translated it incorrectly, if the array elements are double (would be nice if you told us), the original loop did 3 floating point operations per iteration, the wrongly unrolled loop does 7 floating pointer operations per iteration, obviously for half as many iterations, still 16.7% more floating point operations.

Comment: My mistake; the sums are indeed doubles.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the intent of the code (due to missing parentheses in the original probably) - you need to sum 4 consecutive locations per iteration.

Comment: Well, an unrolled loop should do exactly the same thing as the original loop does, not exactly the same thing that the original loop was intended to do.